# jQuery - set the value of a select to one of its options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How can I set the value of a select input field to the value of the first option that is not disabled

for eg., in this field, the selected value is 1. How can I change this value to the next non-disabled option, ie. 2 ?

```
<select>
  <option disabled="disabled" value="1">1</option
  <option value="2">2</option
  <option disabled="disabled" value="3">3</option
  <option value="4">4</option
</select>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for your given example, I would use:

`$("select option:not([disabled])").first().attr("selected", "selected");`

if your select had a specific ID ("#foo" for example):

`$("#foo option:not([disabled])").first().attr("selected", "selected");`

Comment: I edited the snippet a few minutes ago from `.first` to `.first()` Were you using the old code?

Comment: in your html, do the `option` tags actually end with `</option`? It looks like they're missing the close bracket (should be `</option>`)

Comment: This doesn't work in Safari and possibly other browsers. Mpen's answer with :enabled:first works though. Here's a code pen example http://codepen.io/martinkrulltott/pen/zrKvRj

Comment: Using `attr()` is not reliable. It might not update select field visually. You can however explicitly change the value of select with `val()` instead. Like this: `$('select').val( availableOptionValue );` or use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Answer (score 5):

A bit cleaner than the other solutions:

```
$('#select_id').find('option:enabled:first').prop('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id-for-select option:not(:disabled):first').click()
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be a :first at the end of the selector?

Comment: Heh, yeah.  My edit to that effect crossed with your comment entry.

Comment: You'd need to set up an ID for the select tag; this can be whatever you like, and replace `id-for-select` in my example with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#select-id-here option:enabled').first().attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

set the selected property of the option:

```
<option id="value2" value="2">2</option>

document.getElementById('value2').selected = true;
```

Comment: I think the point is that one does not know beforehand which is the first enabled value...